# Read a php file that returned html

Tags: php, html

I tried to use:

```
file_get_contents("www.example.com/example.php");
```

but it did not work, I think it's because it is a php file. It works if it is "example.html".
I do not want the php code, it is the back-end and i understand that's impossible. All i want from "example.php" is the html within it. Because the layout is:

```
<?php
//php
?>
<html>
</html>
```

So although it is a php file, is there a way of returning it's front-end code into a string?

Thanks.

Comment: What about it didn't work? PHP code is processed before being sent to the browser so all that is output is HTML so this should work just fine.

Comment: You can use cURL then return (echo) the response

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the protocol:

```
file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/example.php");
```

Otherwise, it thinks it's just a filename on the server.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a web URL to `file_get_contents()` you're making basically a normal http request to that URL, which means it's impossible to get any PHP back since the web server sends only HTML to the client and you're asking the client for the content of the page.

So if you do (source: PHP manual):

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

You will echo the HTML of that URL which you stored (as a string) in `$homepage`.

Your mistake is that you forgot to include the protocol (http or https).